# How to publish to npm using scripts in package.json?

Tags: npm

In my project, I have a requirement where I need to publish a package to 2 registries.

Currently, whenever I need to publish, I do the following steps.

1. `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and then `npm publish`.
2. `npm config set registry http://npm-registry.myorg.com` and then `npm publish`

This becomes a tiring process for me as there are a lot of new changes that I publish. So I thought of reducing some work by creating a script in `package.json` which can do this automatically.

This is what I added.

```
{
 scripts: {
  "deploy:private": "npm config set registry http://npm-registry.myorg.com && npm publish",
  "deploy:public": "npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm publish"
  }
}
```

So when I run `yarn deploy:private`, it gives below to me

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

How can I resolve this, please help?

----------UPDATE-----------

After googling I have found this https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow

Based on this I have set my token as env variable and in the project I have created a local .npmrc, with below contents

.npmrc file

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
//npm-registry.tokopedia.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN_PRIVATE}
```

But still, I get the error when I try to run the above commands.

Comment: You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

Comment: Hi @Andreas do I need to add this in the starting of command like this, `npm adduser && npm config set registry http://npm-registry.myorg.com && npm publish`

Comment: I already have the token in the .npmrc for the respective registries, do I need to do npm adduser?